# Integer => Digit, and vice versa

Tags: java, integer

is there a way in Java to convert an Integer to single digits, and vice versa. Like this:

So I have the number 345. I want to break it down to 3, 4 and 5 - three seperate numbers.

I have the numbers 3, 4 and 5. I want to put them together to make 345?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've tried Strings, but casting String to Int seems to be impossible. I also tried using very fancy multiplication methods, which didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can easily convert it to a character array, and go from there:

```
char[] parts = Integer.toString(value).toCharArray();
int[] digits = new int[parts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  digits[i] = parts[i] - '0';
}
```

(You don't really *need* the char array here - you could just use the string and use `length()` and `charAt()` instead of `length` and the indexer - but I find this clearer.)

Then to reassemble, just do the reverse - create a `char[]` from the digits (by adding `'0'` to each), then create a string from the `char[]`, then use `Integer.parseInt`.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a combination of `mod` and `divide`.

Here is a short method -

```
public void integerToSingleDigit(int number){
 while (number > 0) {
    System.out.print(number % 10 + " "); // get u the right most single digit
    number = number / 10; // remove the single digit from the right
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be the following

```
for (char c : String.valueOf(numberToSplit).toCharArray()) {
  int digit = Character.getNumericValue(c);
}
```